# How to return properties of an object instance being returned?

Tags: javascript

My Parse cloud code has a query that returns the results in the form of object instances. For example, if the query finds one match, it returns an instance of `userCategory`, and all its properties.

What I want to do is reference certain properties of the `"User categories that match search"` instance being returned, and return those, such as its `minPrice`, `maxPrice`, `itemLocation`, and `itemCondition`. This way, I can use them in the iOS app that's receiving this data. Let me know if I can be more clear on anything.

**Edit**: I've tried doing a for loop like so, and it is returning "undefined":

```
for (var i = 0; i < userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length; i++)
              {
                console.log('hello' + userCategoriesMatchingTop2[i].itemCondition);
              }
```

**Edit 2**: This is what's printed in Parse's log:

```
I2014-05-22T18:59:35.059Z] v224: Ran cloud function eBayCategorySearch for user jKs5QpXjpd with:
  Input: {"item":"iphone 5 16gb"}
  Result: {"results":[{"Number of top categories":1},{"Top category Ids":["9355"]},{"Top category names":["Cell Phones & Smartphones"]},{"Number of matches":1},{"User categories that match search":[{"parent":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"jKs5QpXjpd"},"categoryId":"9355","itemCondition":"new","itemLocation":"US","maxPrice":"400","minPrice":"250","objectId":"AgsUJ2PjTA","createdAt":"2014-05-15T20:45:32.811Z","updatedAt":"2014-05-15T20:46:37.466Z","__type":"Object","className":"userCategory"}]}]}
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.209Z] Top category Ids: 9355
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.210Z] Top category Names: Cell Phones & Smartphones
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.313Z] helloundefined
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.313Z] userCategory comparison success!
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.314Z] [{"parent":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"jKs5QpXjpd"},"categoryId":"9355","itemCondition":"new","itemLocation":"US","maxPrice":"400","minPrice":"250","objectId":"AgsUJ2PjTA","createdAt":"2014-05-15T20:45:32.811Z","updatedAt":"2014-05-15T20:46:37.466Z","__type":"Object","className":"userCategory"}]
I2014-05-22T18:59:36.315Z] User categories that match search: [object Object]
```

Here's the function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*App ID goes here*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {


  // parses results

          var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          var items = [];

          httpresponse.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
            itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
              result.item.forEach(function(item) {
                items.push(item);
              });
            });
          });


  // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), returns top two IDs and their respective names


          var categoryIdResults = {};

          // Collect two most frequent categoryIds
          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
            if (categoryIdResults[id]) categoryIdResults[id]++;
            else categoryIdResults[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(categoryIdResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryIdResults[b]-categoryIdResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top category Ids: ' + top2.join(', '));


          var categoryNameResults = {};

          // Collect two most frequent categoryNames  
          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var categoryName = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryName;
            if (categoryNameResults[categoryName]) categoryNameResults[categoryName]++;
            else categoryNameResults[categoryName] = 1;
          });  


          var top2Names = Object.keys(categoryNameResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryNameResults[b]-categoryNameResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top category Names: ' + top2Names.join(', '));



  // compare categoryIdResults to userCategory object

          //Extend the Parse.Object class to make the userCategory class
          var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");

          //Use Parse.Query to generate a new query, specifically querying the userCategory object.
          query = new Parse.Query(userCategory);

          //Set constraints on the query.
          query.containedIn('categoryId', top2);
          query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())

          //Submit the query and pass in callback functions.
          var isMatching = false;
          query.find({
            success: function(results) {
              var userCategoriesMatchingTop2 = results;
              console.log("userCategory comparison success!");
              console.log(results);
              if (userCategoriesMatchingTop2 && userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length > 0) {
                isMatching = true;
              }

              response.success({
                "results": [
                  { "Number of top categories": top2.length },
                          { "Top category Ids": top2 },
                        { "Top category names": top2Names },   
                         { "Number of matches": userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length }, 
         { "User categories that match search": userCategoriesMatchingTop2 },
                ]
              });

              console.log('User categories that match search: ' + results)
            },
            error: function(error) {
              //Error Callback
              console.log("An error has occurred");
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
  },
          error: function (httpResponse) {
              console.log('error!!!');
              response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
          }
     });
});
```

And here's how the data looks when being returned:

```
2014-05-22 12:04:09.901 Parse+Storyboard[9715:60b] '{
    results =     (
                {
            "Number of top categories" = 1;
        },
                {
            "Top category Ids" =             (
                9355
            );
        },
                {
            "Top category names" =             (
                "Cell Phones & Smartphones"
            );
        },
                {
            "Number of matches" = 1;
        },
                {
            "User categories that match search" =             (
                "<userCategory:AgsUJ2PjTA:(null)> {\n    categoryId = 9355;\n    itemCondition = new;\n    itemLocation = US;\n    maxPrice = 400;\n    minPrice = 250;\n    parent = \"<PFUser:jKs5QpXjpd>\";\n}"
            );
        },
                {
            "Condition of user category that matches search" = "<userCategory:AgsUJ2PjTA:(null)> {\n    categoryId = 9355;\n    itemCondition = new;\n    itemLocation = US;\n    maxPrice = 400;\n    minPrice = 250;\n    parent = \"<PFUser:jKs5QpXjpd>\";\n}";
        }
    );
}'
```